# Why I can't run a newly created Docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I created two new images `anubh_custom_build_image/ubuntu_bionic:version1` & `ubuntu_bionic_mldev:version1` from the base image `ubuntu:bionic`. The purpose of creating the custom-built ubuntu-docker images was to use Linux system on windows platform. I have faced many issues in past one such is installing a new version of [tensorflow library](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/guide/autograph) `! pip install -q tf-nightly`, I can't find a substitute of `!` to run this command on windows cmd-prompt/PowerShell. Moreover, I want to invest more time on my codebase rather than fixing the issues on different OS. So, I pull the latest Ubuntu image from docker, installed a bunch of libraries for my usage and committed using docker commit command:

`docker commit 503130713dff ubuntu_bionic_MLdev:version1`

I can see the images using :

```
PS C:\Users\anubh> docker image ls
REPOSITORY                               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu_bionic_mldev                      version1            e7d1b154b69f        21 hours ago        9.33GB
anubh_custom_build_image/ubuntu_bionic   version1            3c98f8954731        22 hours ago        9.33GB
tensorflow/tensorflow                    latest              2c8d1fd8bde4        2 days ago          1.25GB
ubuntu                                   bionic              735f80812f90        2 weeks ago         83.5MB
ubuntu                                   latest              735f80812f90        2 weeks ago         83.5MB
floydhub/dl-docker                       cpu                 0b9fc622f1b7        2 years ago         2.87GB
```

When I tried to spin-up the containers using these images, The following command ran without any error.

```
PS C:\Users\anubh> docker run anubh_custom_build_image/ubuntu_bionic:version1
PS C:\Users\anubh> docker run ubuntu_bionic_mldev:version1
```

**EDIT:**

The issue is that run command is executing but the containers aren't spinning up for the above two images. I apologize for attaching the wrong error message in the first post, I edited it now. The below two containers were spined-up using `docker run -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow` & `docker run ubuntu:bionic` commands.

```
PS C:\Users\anubh> docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
94d59b217b70        tensorflow/tensorflow   "/run_jupyter.sh --a…"   21 hours ago        Up 21 hours         6006/tcp, 8888/tcp   boring_clarke
503130713dff        ubuntu:bionic           "bash"                   38 hours ago        Up 38 hours                              awesome_bardeen
```

- Could anyone suggest what I am missing for running these images `anubh_custom_build_image/ubuntu_bionic:version1` & `ubuntu_bionic_mldev:version1` from the base image `ubuntu:bionic` as
  containers?
- Also, I can't find the location of any of these images on my disk.
  Could anyone also suggest where to look for inside Windows    OS?

NOTE: I will write a dockerfile in future to build a custom image, but for now, I want to use the `commit` command to create new image & use them.

Comment: This is the one that makes sense:
docker run anubh_custom_build_image/ubuntu_bionic:version1

But on your printscreen, you are missing the tag, and docker says that the 'latest' cannot be found. Please paste output for the ones when you ask the tag "version1"

Comment: The second `docker run` should work. You have 6 images including `anubh_custom_build_image/ubuntu_bionic`. If you don't specify the tag (`:[TAG]`) then a value of `latest` is assumed. You don't have an image for `anubh_custom_build_image/ubuntu_bionic` tagged `latest` so you can't omit the tag. What you wrote (but didn't show in your console) `docker run anubh_custom_build_image/ubuntu_bionic:version1` should work as should `docker run ubuntu_bionic_mldev:version1`.

Comment: Please don't paste error messages as screen shots.  Copy and paste the actual text of the error into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `docker run` command doesn't work because you don't have the `:version1` tag at the end of it.  (Your question claims you do, but the actual errors you quote don't have it.)

However: if this was anything more than a simple typo, the community would probably be unable to help you, because you have no documentation about what went into your image.  (And if not "the community", then "you, six months later, when you discover your image has a critical security vulnerability".)  Learn how the Dockerfile system works and use `docker build` to build your custom images.  Best-practice workflows tend to not use `docker commit` at all.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. Mistakenly, I have attached the last screenshot wrong. I wasn't supposed to do that. I do aware of the typo error. Please avoid it. The issue is even after providing the version, the command runs but the container never spins up, as shown in the updated post.